# How can i select values from a vector in R using logical operators?

Tags: r, select, vector, merge, subset

I have a vector of time displacement:

`time_displ <- c(17, 16, 20, 24, 22, 15, 21, 15, 17, 22)`

And I want to select only the values which are greater than 20.

I used this:
`twentyuplogical <- time_displ[1:10] > 20`

But it gives me a vector of TRUES and FALSE.

How can i make a subset with only the values with > 20

Comment: `time_displ[time_displ> 20]`

Answer (score 2):

```
time_displ_new <- time_displ[time_displ>20]
```

or

```
time_displ_new <- subset(time_displ, time_displ>20)
```

Either will give you a new vector containing only the values which are >20.

Answer (score 0):

```
time_displ <- c(17, 16, 20, 24, 22, 15, 21, 15, 17, 22)

# to get the indices
which(time_displ > 20)
#  [1]  4  5  7 10

# to get the values
time_displ[time_displ>20]
# [1] 24 22 21 22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create logical vector (true if element is  greater than 20 and false if it's not) and use it in time_displ to select elements with true.

```
logical_vect <- time_displ>20 #that returns logical state for all elements in time_displ
greater <- time_displ[logical_vect]
```

Or in one line

```
greater <- time_displ[time_displ>20]
```